# How to enforce lower case URLs just for specific pages of ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config

I use this code in `web.config` to enforce lower case URLs for enhancing SEO.

Now my problem is in a part of website I use some case sensitive `GUID`s which I don't want them to change to lower case. How can I prevent changing URLs of these pages to get lower?

Thanx in advance.

```
<rule name="Lower Case URLs" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="WebResource.axd" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself. We should handle it with the following code in `global.asax` file in `Application_BeginRequest` method.

```
if (Request.RawUrl.Contains("/[specific part of website]/"))
{
    RouteTable.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
}
```